# Plotting Time and Groupby Count

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

Hi all sorry if this question seems rudimentary, but I have a table, with the InvoiceDate as the index:

```
            InvoiceNo | StockCode | Description| Quantity   |  InvoiceDate       | UnitPrice |   Country
InvoiceDate 536635       85123A          shirt         5        2010-12-01 08:26:00     50      United Kingdom
```

with 390,000 rows, and I have been trying to create a scatter plot/line plot of  month vs a count of the groupby 'description' column. I tried writing this:

```
df.groupby([df.index.month, 'description']).count().plot()
```

but this returns a bar graph of that returns all columns without time being plotted. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) also:

```
df.groupby([df.index.month,'description'])['description'].count().unstack().plot()
```

Or:

```
df.groupby([df.index.month,'description']).size().unstack().plot()
```

Comment: Thank you! If I just wanted the top 5 best sellers, I tried adding a .head() but that doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: @CuriousStudent - i think need [`nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html)